Printing / Exporting images with facial recognition
There are a number of applications out there that can embed facial recognition into images (Lightroom Classic, ACDSee, XNViewMP...) However, I have not been able to figure out how to either export a new image, or print the image with an caption or something that identifies people in the image.
I have thousands of genealogy photos that I have been converting to digital and tagging. The facial recognition is great from for locating and managing. But, thinking about long term preservation of the originals, I would like to print out something that identifies who is in the photos.
ACDSee allows you to use their "People" tag in captions when printing, but it is simply a list of names, it doesn't actually identify the "who." If you have a group of ten people, don't actually know who "John Smith" is.
Am I missing something in these applications, or is this just not something that can be done?
